# Parsing JSON output with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I've been trying to parse this JSON code (It's `$customer_cart['products']` output):

```
{
    "Bag0145cm":{
        "name":"Pizza",
        "code":"Bag0145cm",
        "price":"9.50",
        "size":"45cm",
        "short_desc":"Shortdesc",
        "quantity":"1",
        "image":"IMG"
    },
    "Laptop0135cm":{
        "name":"Pizza2",
        "code":"Laptop0135cm",
        "price":"8.00",
        "size":"35cm",
        "short_desc":"Shortdesc",
        "quantity":"1",
        "image":"IMG"
    }
}
```

I'd like to get output all listed product names like this:

```
Pizza
Pizza2
```

I've tried this kind of code but getting foreach error

```
$array = json_decode($customer_cart['products'], true);

foreach($array as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo $product['name'];` instead of `echo $product->name;`?

Comment: For future reference: when you're getting an error, include it in the question. It'll help us identify your problem quicker. Also, make sure to [look for it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/26572398#26572398).

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
$array = json_decode($customer_cart['products'], true);

foreach($array as $product) {
    echo $product['name'];
}
```

json_decode with "true" flag will return you associative array
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you have passed `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()`, meaning it will be returned as an associative array, not an object.

Try using this instead:

```
$array = json_decode($customer_cart['products'], true);

foreach($array as $product) {
    echo $product['name'];
}
```

Notice that I'm using `$product['name']` instead of `$product->name`, as we are dealing with an array, not an object.